# How to print category tree in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table for competences. I have made it like a parent-child relation, so there is for example driver-licence as a row, and car-driver-licence as another row, having 'driver-licence' as a parent.

Can this be printed in MS-Access, in a report or something? Printed like a tree, or as a list like:

1. driver-license
2. car-driver-license under driver-licence

The table has 5 columns, and a select query looks like this:

SELECT Kompetenser.[ID], Kompetenser.[created_date], Kompetenser.[namn], Kompetenser.[Metakompetens], Kompetenser.[beskrivning] FROM Kompetenser;

where Kompetenser.[Metakompetens] is a 'Number' (swedish 'Tal') referring to the same table.

I found a post that is the same question, and has an answer, but the I can't run the sql:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797072/5730322

(It gives a list with rows starting with the parent though, but it's ok)

I tried to make a query:

```
SELECT
L0.namn AS Cat0,
L1.namn AS Cat1,
L2.namn AS Cat2,
L3.namn AS Cat3,
L4.namn AS Cat4,
L5.namn AS Cat5,
L6.namn AS Cat6,
L7.namn AS Cat7
FROM
Kompetenser AS L0
LEFT JOIN Kompetenser AS L1
ON L0.ID=L1.[Metakompetens]
LEFT JOIN AS L2
ON L1.ID = L2.Metakompetens
LEFT JOIN Kompetenser AS L3
ON L2.ID = L3.Metakompetens
LEFT JOIN Kompetenser AS L4
ON L3.ID = L4.Metakompetens
LEFT JOIN Kompetenser AS L5
ON L4.ID = L5.Metakompetens
LEFT JOIN Kompetenser AS L6
ON L5.ID = L6.Metakompetens
LEFT JOIN Kompetenser AS L7
ON L6.ID = L7.Metakompetens
WHERE isnull(L0.Metakompetens)
```

It says (translated fr. swedish):

Syntax error (operator missing) i query 'L0.ID=L1.[Metakompetens] ... to the end of the query

So the question is how to fix my sql.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your second `LEFT JOIN  AS L2` is missing the table name. It should be `LEFT JOIN <MISSING_TABLE_NAME> AS L2`. Replace `<MISSING_TABLE_NAME>` with the name of the table you wish to JOIN. It should probably be `...LEFT JOIN Kompetenser AS L2...`. Just guessing.

Comment: Thanks, I added it but still same error. Also cant get clear about if [ ] brackets are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MS Access join syntax is peculiar.  When your query needs to have more than one, you have to start using parentheses.  More specifically, in order to introduce the next join, you need to enclose the previous join in parentheses.  For instance, this is what it would look like for two joins:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  (Table1
  JOIN Table2 ON ...)
  JOIN Table3 ON ...
```

And this is how your query would need to change after adding a third join:

```
SELECT
  ...
FROM
  ((Table1
  JOIN Table2 ON ...)
  JOIN Table3 ON ...)
  JOIN Table4 ON ...
```

Proceed with adding as many parentheses as necessary in this manner to cover all the joins required for the query.

This is irrespective of the type of join (left, right, inner).

Comment: That's good to know